# How to write a parsing template to the end of the line?

Tags: regex

[My regular expresion](https://regex101.com/r/IYLHSX/1):

```
^(([(Title|Relaese Year|Format|Stars):]{0,})([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}))
```

The text I apply it to looks like:

```
Title: Blazing Saddles
Release Year: 1974
Format: VHS
Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn
```

Here comes the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the grouping construct (`(...)`) when placed inside square brackets stops being a grouping construct and all chars start matching themselves. However, the problem you have is with `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}` that matches 0 or more alphanumeric chars. It does not match spaces and any punctuation or symbols.

You may use

```
^(Title|Release Year|Format|Stars): *(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wDUL3Y/1)

With `(.*)`, you will capture into Group 2 any zero or more chars up to the end of a line.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (if the multiline mode is enabled)
- `(Title|Release Year|Format|Stars)` - Group 1: any of the values inside the group
- `: *` - a colon and 0+ spaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars to the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am just starting to learn regular expressions, which is why I ask stupid questions.

Comment: In PHP, you need to use `'~^(Title|Release Year|Format|Stars): *(.*)~m'`, or, better, `'~^(Title|Release Year|Format|Stars):\h*(.*)~m'` with `preg_match_all`.